# When chrome opens a file in a new tab, how do I get it to open in my text editor

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, google-chrome-headless

I have links in my HTML that link to a source code file on my computer, I want to click on that link and have it open in my code editor (I use neovim).

how do I go about this?
I thought I might be able to use chrome's remote debugging tools and watch for a new tab opened event and intercept that to open it in my text editor.

Comment: Associate the file extension with an app in Windows, configure your browser settings to open (rather than save) files with that extension.